# SP for Get ID or Insert ID

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a SP in SQL 2008. If a value is already present in database it will return me its Id otherwise it will insert the value and will return Id of the newly inserted value. How to create this SP for a table

```
Title { Id(int), Name(nvarchar(50) }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If you are sending in a known id value don't you already know there is a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, assuming the id column is an identity column:

```
create table YourTable (id int identity, name nvarchar(50))
go
create procedure dbo.YourSp(
    @name varchar(50))
as
    declare @id int

    set transaction isolation level serializable
    begin transaction
    select @id = id from dbo.YourTable where name = @name
    if @id is null
        begin
        insert dbo.YourTable (name) values (@name)
        set @id = scope_identity()
        end
    commit transaction
    return @id
go
```

If you test this like:

```
declare @rc int
exec @rc = dbo.YourSp 'John'; select @rc
exec @rc = dbo.YourSp 'John'; select @rc
exec @rc = dbo.YourSp 'George'; select @rc
```

It will print `1, 1, 2`.  If consistency is not that important, you can omit the transaction related statements from the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertIfNew

    (
    @outputID int Output,
    @Id int,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
    )

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT Id FROM Title WHERE Id=@Id

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Title (Name)
VALUES     (@Name)

SET @outputID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

ELSE
SET @outputID=@Id   

COMMIT TRANSACTION  

    RETURN
```